# Umbraco Custom Package Installation Failed

Tags: umbraco

I'm using umbraco 6.2.6 and try to package some of the umbraco cms content in my PC to the another umbraco cms in different machine. To create the package I following this tutorial http://www.uquickstart.com/umbraco-tips-and-tools/package-up-your-umbraco-website.

After I create the package then installed it to another machine, All works fine for (document type, data type, templates, etc) however my content/page is not installed by this package.

P.S. I'm sure my packages already contain the content/page

One of my colleagues say that eventually sometimes we need to included the content/page from the parent to add the content/page. For example the news is under the home sections (Home -> News), so to add the news to the other machine we need to add the home as their basic parent.. Is this true?

Or are there another way or idea to package this item then installed on another machine.. Any idea would be helpful..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes.  You'll also need to include in your package the Document Type for your home page.  Basically, in order for your content to be included in the package and successfully created, you need to also include any parent nodes so that the Content Tree remains valid.

Even if your package includes the specified content nodes, because you haven't included the parent node those nodes won't be created because the resulting content tree would be invalid.

**UPDATE**:

If a home node exists already and your package adds another, then you will end up with two - the new one will have a unique name and may be unpublished though.

The other problem to consider is if a Document Type already exists with the same name as one included in your package - in this case, your new Document Type won't be created, but the package should still create a node based on the existing Document Type - this is where things get messy.  I haven't tried in a long time, but the package install may simply fail to create the related content node as the properties won't necessarily match up.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot, I tried to include the parent and it works normally.. But If like that what if the current one is Home -> Article, FAQ. and I tried to insert news under home.. I add Home as parent content to be included in the package and choose to include all subitems..(For page/content only one that can be choose either the item it self or the parent with the all subitems) Are that means I add the news page under home and all the article and faq page will be changed also according to my package (because the parent page is choosed with all its subitems)?

Comment: Expanded my answer to (hopefully) answer your question.